# Concatenate A Row from columns of another table with multiple row

Tags: mysql, sql, woocommerce, group-by, pivot

I have developed an application related WooCommerce. Therefore, I must use WooCommerce's database tables.

I am a stuck at a point. I would like to concatenate a table to another table with multiple row which has foreign_id.

For example:

There are 2 tables in WooCommerce. These are `wp_posts` and `wp_postmeta`.

The `wp_posts` contains following table.

```
| ID   | post_title | post_name
| 1682 | foo        | foo
| 1681 | bar        | bar
```

The `wp_postmeta` contains following table.

```
| post_id | meta_key              | meta_value
| 1682    | _regular_price        | 100
| 1682    | _sale_price           | 99
| 1681    | _regular_price        | 300
| 1681    | _sale_price           | 299
```

I would like to write sql query which result in following table.

```
| ID   | post_title | post_name  | _regular_price | _sale_price |
| 1682 | foo        | foo        | 100            | 99
| 1681 | bar        | bar        | 300            | 299
```

Thank you so much.

All The Best,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
select
    p.id,
    p.post_title,
    p.post_name,
    max(case when m.meta_key = '_regular_price' then m.meta_value end) regular_price,
    max(case when m.meta_key = '_sale_price'    then m.meta_value end) sale_price
from wp_posts p
inner join wp_postmeta m on m.post_id = p.id
group by p.id, p.post_title, p.post_name
```

If the meta table has a large number of rows per post, you can optimize the query with the following `where` clause:

```
where m.meta_key in ('_regular_price', '_sale_price')
```